# DeleteByQueryPlugin cannot be resolved to a type && FRAMELESS_COMPILE_ENABLED : NoSuchFieldError

Tags: elasticsearch, playframework-2.0, elasticsearch-plugin

Iam having the following error when i upgraded the elasticsearch to 2.3.2 and used delete-by-query plugin . The code is something like this

```
 Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder().build();
    TransportClient transportClient = null;
    for (String node : nodes.trim().split(",")) {
    String[] parts = node.split(":");
    transportClient=TransportClient.builder().settings(settings)
    .addPlugin(DeleteByQueryPlugin.class).build();
    transportClient = transportClient.addTransportAddress(
    new    InetSocketTransportAddress(
    InetAddress.getByName(parts[0]),Integer.valueOf(parts[1])));
```

And the Error:

```
play.exceptions.CompilationException: DeleteByQueryPlugin cannot be resolved to a type
        at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler$2.acceptResult(ApplicationCompiler.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.handleInternalException(Compiler.java:676)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:520)
        at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler.compile(ApplicationCompiler.java:282)
        at play.classloading.ApplicationClasses$ApplicationClass.compile(ApplicationClasses.java:281)
        at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.loadApplicationClass(ApplicationClassloader.java:166)
        at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.loadClass(ApplicationClassloader.java:84)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at play.plugins.PluginCollection.loadPlugins(PluginCollection.java:168)
        at play.Play.init(Play.java:303)
        at play.server.Server.main(Server.java:162)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FRAMELESS_COMPILE_ENABLED
        at play.modules.sass.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:44)
        at play.modules.sass.Plugin.onLoad(Plugin.java:15)
        at play.plugins.PluginCollection.initializePlugin(PluginCollection.java:251)
        at play.plugins.PluginCollection.loadPlugins(PluginCollection.java:185)
        at play.Play.init(Play.java:303)
        at play.server.Server.main(Server.java:162)
```

Can any one give me any pointers how can i solve this error

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about which Play environment/version you have?

Comment: 1.)play version is 1.2.7.2 
2.) java8 . 
3.) I added the
                     org.elasticsearch.plugin -> delete-by-query 2.3.0
      in dependencies.yml file.